Could we add this feedback regarding Minecraft command questions to the review queues?
A lot of Minecraft command questions we get are missing info.
Generally when this happens, someone will post this comment:

On Minecraft commands questions, please see our guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question, especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

or something similar.
Could we make that part of the review feedback?
Alternatively, we could follow @Robotnik's suggestion and make this show up as a warning that pops up if the minecraft-commands tag is selected.
The tag warning is already implemented. However, adding this feedback to review queues would still be useful, as we still frequently get low-detail questions that keep getting the same copy/paste comment, and making this part of a review queue feedback comment would save a lot of time.

Hmm, we might be able to add a tag warning, so if someone uses [Minecraft-commands] we could potentially pop up advice for what to add there?

@Robotnik That might even be better, so it doesn’t get flagged initially. Might make it more likely to get ignored though.

That’s probably a better option overall though.

I'd like this kind of customizations on our review queue

This question is similar to: Should we add a tag warning to [minecraft-commands]?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. ([tag:minecraft-commands] already has a tag warning)

@pppery Oh, I didn't know there was already a tag warning. Adding the feedback to review queues would still be helpful though, since we get a lot of questions that are missing info. It also saves time typing it all out.

But that feedback is already part of the warning, right?

@Joachim Yes, but questions are posted frequently enough without relevant info that it would be useful.

Oh, wait, you want to make this a canned comment, whereas the suggested dupe is about the tag warning. Apologies, I retracted my close-vote

In the "edit" part of the comment example above, I use [edit], which is a shorthand link to the edit page for the post the comment is on. For instance, clicking the [edit] link in this comment will direct you to the edit page for this meta post.
